# Scalability limits of federated database on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We plan to use federated azure SQL database in our next project, because we need a database solution that can handle a very large amount of concurrent requests - inserts, selects, updates, etc.

However, there is a hard limit of [180 concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646846/sql-azure-connectivity-issue-after-concurrent-connections) on a database instance.

The problem is that even if we use federations, every connection must connect to federation root first (just a regular sql server database). Then this server redirect our client to the federation member that contains the required data:

```
-- this statement redirect us from federation root db to federation member db
USE FEDERATION MyFederation (uid = 0xFF) WITH RESET, FILTERING = ON;
```

Does it mean, that there is no (easy) way to scale beyond 180 concurrent requests on the federation root server?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the SQL Database Premium reservations, which eliminate the connection limit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn369873.aspx

it is in preview currently, but that doesn't mean you can't start developing on it.  You don't get an SLA in preview, but with the retry block and using multiple instances it could be somewhat mitigated.

Comment: I think you have your math wrong..it is more expensive, but not 50x.  One thing developers/architects don't consider is that with SQL server you get persisted storage AND an execution engine.  For example, azure table storage almost requires additional LINQ processing unless the query is super simple.

Comment: It all depends on how large your database is. For my 5gb SQL Azure database it costs me around $26 per month. The low end P1 price is $30 per day or around $900 per month which is 35x higher.

Comment: I am not saying this pricing is bad because you are essentially going from a shared host to a dedicated host, but it is certainly a lot more expensive.

Comment: @Craig Agreed in your scenario, but I would assume any database requiring federated scaling (as is the context of the question) is going to be greatly larger than a 5 gig max.

Comment: That is also a question I am interested in knowing. If I have a 5gb database on SQLAzure with 1000 users how will it scale.

Comment: Can you even host a federated database using the new Premium services?