# exceeded max_user_connections in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, windows, azure

I know, this question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034583/mysql-error-exceeded-the-max-connections-per-hour).

But, my question is related with windows azure server. I am in Free version of windows azure right now. I tried it with Shared version too. But, sometimes I am getting the same error for mysql connection.

**ERROR**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'username' has exceeded the
'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 4)'
```

How can I resolve this problem ? Do I need to increase number of instances in azure management portal? My website is in php.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what about closing a connection after using it? you can increase it like this... `connectionString="Server=XXX;Database=XXX;User Id=XXX;password=XXX; connection timeout=0; Max Pool Size = 500; Pooling = True"`

Comment: You mean, Do I need to close connection after each query?

Comment: if you are creating a connection to the database for each query it seems like you should be able to streamline it to connect either once for a batch of queries or to close each connection after getting the result. also see this reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646846/sql-azure-connectivity-issue-after-concurrent-connections

Comment: alright. Thanks. @John Ruddell

Comment: did that solve your issue?

Comment: I need to work on caching in azure. o.w. I need to `unset` query object after each query in my project.

Comment: :) it'll make a better programmer out of you!